# Should I use NSDate to track arrival time and lateness?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, time, nsdate, date-arithmetic

I want to make time calculations and I can't figure out what class to use, should I use `NSDate`?

I want that the user will enter the time he should be at work every day and the app will show him his average late/early time in minutes.

**Better explanation:**
When the user launches the app for the first time, the app asks him when he should be at work and when he should leave. The app tracks when the user arrives/leaves (using the work address and geofencing) and calculates the average late and average early of the user to work. When the user opens the app he sees two labels, one for "average late" and one for "average early".

Should I use `NSDate` for that or is there a better way?

Comment: Best tutorial reference for your question is - http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/dates

Comment: I would go with NSDateComponents, as it is not really connected to the single point in time that a NSDate instance represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just comparing durations, `NSTimeInterval` is the type for you (it's really a `float` number of milliseconds that explains its intent to the reader).

`NSDate` is necessary for calculations that need to begin or end with actual clock time.

**EDIT** With the more specific problem described: given a user's daily work start, compute deviation from that time when upon arrival at work, the key calculation involves `NSDate`.

It aims to answer the question: is the user on time or not, right now, vs the actual clock?  The key params to this calculation is the current time `NSDate` and the user's planned arrival time `NSDate` that can be saved as simple scalars and converted to NSDate via `NSDateComponents`...

```
// core location triggered an arrival notification and we call this
// assumes a "User" class that knows user state, like the time user is due at work
-(void)userJustArrived:(User *)myUser {
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *dueAtWork = [myUser dueAtWork];
    NSTimeInterval lateness = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:dueAtWork];

    // a negative lateness means user is early
    if (lateness > 0)
        NSLog(@"you are %f milliseconds late.  perhaps you should go into standup comedy", lateness);
}

// on the user class, due at work produces an NSDate from what you would
// have stored earlier as the time when a user is expected at work
- (NSDate *)dueAtWork {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    // these are given as user state, the user's planned start time
    components.hour = self.dueAtWorkHour;
    components.minute = self.dueAtWorkMinute;
    return [components date];
}
```

Comment: I'll try to explain myself better. When the user launches the app for the first time, the app asks him when he should be at work and when he should leave. The app tracks when the user arrives/leaves (using the work address and geofencing) and calculates the average late and average early of the user to work. When the user opens the app he sees two labels, one for "average late" and one for "average early". So, I hope you understand :) . What is the best way to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Those are definitely NSDate questions because they pertain to actual times on a clock ("what time").  I think this problem calls for using NSDates (converting input to a NSDate, storing an NSDate, converting to floats only to do arithmetic).

Comment: So how can I store time only on `NSDate`/check if the user arrived at a certain time without reference to the date?

Comment: You will refer to the date.  See the class reference which contains methods like +date that gives the current time (when the geo fence triggers, for example), -earlierDate: -laterDate: comparing two dates, -timeIntervalSinceDate: that produces a difference in milliseconds, etc.  Its very good for this sort of problem,  (The other highly respectable contributors here are correct, too, but a bit abstract, imho)

Comment: Can you maybe give me a code example?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit a coding problem into your question?  Something of the form of: "I'm trying to write a function that takes inputs like x and produces output like y"

Comment: I'm trying to write a function that takes an `NSDate` with a time that takes the user arrived to the office (for example: 09:04am) and calculates the time that was pass since he was should in the office (for example: 09:00am - 4min late).

Comment: is `dueAtWork` a `NSDate` object?

Comment: Yes.  Please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you want to keep track of "human" time (i.e. date and times that you would find on a calendar or clock), the tool you want is `NSDateComponents`, coupled with `NSCalendar`. The goal of `NSDate` is to keep track of absolute moments in time,  (*) in terms of seconds since some reference moment, which is not usually how people think of time. `NSDate` quickly becomes incorrect and often counterproductive as soon as you are dealing with time zones, Daylight Savings Time, or any other thing that messes up the nice mapping of "seconds since the epoch" and "the clock on the wall."

(*) Put aside Relativity and what not, and assume that we can all agree on when things happen and that time intervals can be combined in commutative and transitive ways in a nice, simple Newtonian universe. Also ignore issues like leap seconds or any other thing that might make things complicated, and you have `NSDate`.

---

Here's an actual implementation that should handle most weirdnesses (like times over midnight). Might not handle DST transitions correctly, but it should get you on the right track.

```
let twelveHours: NSTimeInterval = 12 * 60 * 60

func timeLateBetweenDate(actualDate: NSDate, nominalHour: Int, nominalMinute: Int) -> NSTimeInterval {

    func timeLateOnDate(onDate: NSDate) -> NSTimeInterval {
        let calendar =  NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let expectedDate = calendar.dateBySettingHour(nominalHour, minute: nominalMinute, second: 0, ofDate: onDate, options: [])!

        let todayDifference = actualDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(expectedDate)

        if todayDifference > twelveHours { // Over 12 hours late; should have checked against tomorrow
            return timeLateOnDate(calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: onDate, options: [])!)
        } else if todayDifference < -twelveHours { // Over 12 hours early, should have checked against yesterday
            return timeLateOnDate(calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -1, toDate: onDate, options: [])!)
        }
        else {
            return todayDifference
        }
    }

    return timeLateOnDate(actualDate)
}
```

And in somewhat sloppy ObjC (just transliterated the Swift; this would probably be clearer as a method):

```
NSTimeInterval twelveHours = 12 * 60 * 60;

NSTimeInterval _timeLateOnDate(NSDate *onDate, NSDate *actualDate, NSUInteger nominalHour, NSUInteger nominalMinute) {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *expectedDate = [calendar dateBySettingHour:nominalHour minute: nominalMinute second: 0 ofDate: onDate options: 0];

    NSTimeInterval todayDifference = [actualDate timeIntervalSinceDate:expectedDate];

    if (todayDifference > twelveHours) { // Over 12 hours late; should have checked against tomorrow
        return _timeLateOnDate([calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value: 1 toDate: onDate options: 0],
                               actualDate, nominalHour, nominalMinute);
    } else if (todayDifference < -twelveHours) { // Over 12 hours early, should have checked against yesterday
        return _timeLateOnDate([calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value: -1 toDate: onDate options: 0],
                               actualDate, nominalHour, nominalMinute);
    } else {
        return todayDifference;
    }
}


NSTimeInterval timeLateBetweenDateAndNominalHourMinute(NSDate *actualDate, NSUInteger nominalHour, NSUInteger nominalMinute) {
    return _timeLateOnDate(actualDate, actualDate, nominalHour, nominalMinute);
}
```

Comment: So how can I store time only on `NSDateComponents`/check if the user arrived at a certain time without reference to the date?

Comment: Store just the hour and minutes if that's all you want. You can also store the nominal day, month, and year if that's useful. You can store as many or as few components as you like.

Comment: In order to to do math on an `NSDateComponents`, you will generally need to give it what date you want to consider for those components. That's important if there's a DST time shift during the period. If you're willing to ignore DST time shifts (none of your times will ever be overnight, for instance) then you can just do simple integer math on hours and minutes.

Comment: Can you please give me  a code example on how to calculate user's late time? Because I don't think I understand what you mean. Thank you!

Comment: Put up a simple form, but for corner cases you'll still want date components. Let me see if I can improve a little more

Comment: I'm trying to write a function that takes an NSDate with a time that takes the user arrived to the office (for example: 09:04am) and calculates the time that was pass since he was should in the office (for example: 09:00am - 4min late).

Comment: Just realized I wrote essentially the same function you did, both employing date components and nsdate, both glossing over of 20th century physics.

Answer (score 0):

The time of the day that you want to store is not a date. Something like "Februrary 9th 2016 10:20:30.7 UTC" is a date. "8:30 in the morning" is not a date that NSDate can represent.

When the user enters the time, store the hour and minutes as two numbers.

When the user arrives at work, take the current date, convert it to date components with your local calendar to get today's date, create an NSDate with today's date and the hour and minutes that the user entered, and then you can compare both NSDates. That way, you handle daylight saving time etc. automatically. You even handle the situation where the user entered the date while on holiday in a timezone six hours away from yours.

Please don't ask for code. Writing code is your job. Your job alone.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `NSDateFormatter` to get the set the actual office time for each day. Use `timeIntervalSinceDate:` method on `NSTimeInterval` to calculate the avg late/ early in seconds.

Comment: But how can I ignore the date? I just want to compare the time